# jQuery UI Datepicker range select for three dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am setting three dates in ascending order Request, Submission and Approval respectively and using the [jquery datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#range) for the same. 
The javascript code is as follows:

```
  $('#startDate,#completionDate,#due_date').datepick({
    onSelect: customRange
});

function customRange(dates) {
    if (this.id == 'startDate') {
        $('#due_date').datepick('option', 'minDate', dates[0] || null);
    } else if (this.id == 'due_date') {
        $('#startDate').datepick('option', 'maxDate', dates[0] || null);
        $('#completionDate').datepick('option', 'minDate', dates[0] || null);
    } else {
        $('#due_date').datepick('option', 'maxDate', dates[0] || null);
    }
}
```

But when i select click the function is not called hence even if I clear the completionDate the due_date remains restricted.

The jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/u3pj7/4/)

**Update:**
The issue is same even with a simple range selection [range jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/u3pj7/18/). the function customRange is called on clicking clear and it passes the value undefined.But the minDate or maxDate is not changed. This is same on the site [jquery datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#range)

```
$('#startDate,#completionDate').datepick({
    onSelect: customRange
});


function customRange(dates) { 
   alert(dates[0]);
    if (this.id == 'startDate') { 
        $('#completionDate ').datepick('option','minDate', dates[0] || null); 
    } 
    else { 
        $('#startDate').datepick('option','maxDate', dates[0] || null); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If anyone can suggest a way to hide the clear and close that would also help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in _optionPlugin change the beginning of the function as follows:

```
_optionPlugin: function(target, options, value) {
    target = $(target);
    var inst = target.data(this.propertyName);
    if (!options || (typeof options == 'string' && typeof value == 'undefined')) { // Get option
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue in the plugin in the function `_optionPlugin` and `null` cannot be set...

Code:

```
_optionPlugin: function(target, options, value) {
    target = $(target);
    var inst = target.data(this.propertyName);
    // HERE!
    if (!options || (typeof options == 'string' && value == null)) { // Get option
        var name = options;
        options = (inst || {}).options;
        return (options && name ? options[name] : options);
    }

    if (!target.hasClass(this.markerClassName)) {
        return;
    }
    options = options || {};
    if (typeof options == 'string') {
        var name = options;
        options = {};
        options[name] = value;
    }
    if (options.calendar && options.calendar != inst.options.calendar) {
        var discardDate = function(name) {
            return (typeof inst.options[name] == 'object' ? null : inst.options[name]);
        };
        options = $.extend({defaultDate: discardDate('defaultDate'),
            minDate: discardDate('minDate'), maxDate: discardDate('maxDate')}, options);
        inst.selectedDates = [];
        inst.drawDate = null;
    }
    var dates = inst.selectedDates;
    $.extend(inst.options, options);
    this._setDatePlugin(target[0], dates, null, false, true);
    inst.pickingRange = false;
    inst.drawDate = plugin.newDate(this._checkMinMax(
        (inst.options.defaultDate ? inst.get('defaultDate') : inst.drawDate) ||
        inst.get('defaultDate') || plugin.today(), inst));
    if (!inst.inline) {
        this._attachments(target, inst);
    }
    if (inst.inline || inst.div) {
        this._update(target[0]);
    }
},
```

You can ask the developer to fix the issue, or set a minimal date like:

```
$('#startDate,#completionDate').datepick({
    onSelect: customRange
});

function customRange(dates) { 
    var demo=dates[0] || 'null'
    if (this.id == 'startDate') { 
    $('#completionDate ').datepick('option','minDate', dates[0] || new Date(0)); 
    } 
    else { 
        $('#startDate').datepick('option','maxDate', dates[0] || new Date(2099,12,31)); 
    } 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/f7pVh/

If you want to hide clear and close use:

```
.datepick-cmd-clear {
    display: none
}
.datepick-cmd-close {
    display: none
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/j8t7v/

Answer (score 0):

dont concider as perfact answer but i have analysed your code and tested for many cases my advise is to use    `onClose` 
rather then `onSelect`

and the main issue is with clearing date while closing NULL and [] both applied at by me but in that case some times it returns undefined value for the null.

Comment: it didn't help [onClose fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mudBorn/u3pj7/16/), the problem persists. What would be the event for the clear button click that would be really helpful.

Comment: the onSelect event is fired even on Clear but the minDate or maxDate are retaining there earlier values. Also null and [] are same